# Call function that returns array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to call a function which returns array. It throws some exception 
"Access violation writing location 0xABABABAB"

I am trying to return array as pointer. If I comment line

```
 convertor >> data[row][col];
```

It works. So problem seems with the line

```
convertor >> data[row][col];
```

Any Help

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>


using namespace std;


string * readcsvfile()
{
    string  * data = new string[];
    ifstream file("tradesheet5.csv");

    for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
    {
        string line;
        stringstream newline;

        getline(file, line);

        if (!file.good())
            break;

        newline << line + ",\n";

        for (int col = 0; col < 11; ++col)
        {
            string val;
            getline(newline, val, ',');

            if (!newline.good())
                break;

            stringstream convertor(val);
            convertor >> data[row][col];
        }
    }
    return data;
}

void main()
{
   readcsvfile();
}
```

Comment: `string* data = new string[];` should not compile.

Comment: Better to use `std::vector`.

Comment: The problem is data[row][col].  Also as Jarod said, use std::vector<string>.  Don't use "new".

Comment: What do you expect/want the `convertor >> data[row][col]` to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It looks for me like you didnt initialize anywhere size of the array of strings, so you are accessing not allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
string  * data = new string[];
```

with

```
string data[4][11] = {};
```

if you know the size will never change. 
Then to return you say

```
return &data[0][0];
```

Comment: void main()
      {
   string * data1;
         data1 = readcsvfile();
   cout << data1 << endl;
         cin.get();
         }
This returns the memory address of only first element at 0,0 location. I want values of all elements in array.

Comment: Isn't the address of a C++ array the address of the first element?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a two-dimensional array, I would recommend not using `string *` or even worse a `vector *`.

```
int main(void) //No void main... really, no
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > vCSVFile;
    readcsvfile(vCSVFile);
}

void readcsvfile(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &v)
{
    //[...]
}
```

Do not even consider returning a two-dimensional array. It will get copied and the array in the function destructed. With a large CSV file this might waste take a few minutes or longer. Allocation is a way, but a bad way here.

Also your "Parser" will not work with regular CSV files, keep in mind that these marks `"` can contain between them commas. You will need to process this too.

**Possible CSV:**

```
town, city, "wait, what", 1, 90
```

Comment: I would like to use data imported with "readcsvfile" and do some manipulation over the data. If "readcsvfile" has return type void then what variable it will create in main function and how to use data?

Comment: @user1177819 If took any look at my answer, then you have your answer already. A `void` function has no return type. It does not return anything. But what you do, has a very bad performance. Read my answer, if you are not familiar with C++ yet, I recommend learning the basics first. It seems like you are not familiar with the basic data-types yet. Also... learn about pointers/addresses AND where/how to use them. Without pointers you will have a hard time programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector <string> data;
vector <string> readcsvfile()
{
ifstream file("tradesheet5.csv");
for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
{
    string line,val;
    vector <string> data;
    getline(file, line);

    if(!file.good())
        break;
    stringstream newline(line);
    newline << line + ",\n";

    if(!newline.good())
         break;

    while (getline(newline, val, ','))
         data.push_back(val);
}


return data;
}

int main()
{
readcsvfile();

cin.get();
 }
```

1. problem here is "data" is outside for loop and it does not contain any information. How to get values in "data" outside for loop so that

   ```
   return data
   ```

works

2. How to put all vectors separated by comma into array?